# T-SQL Insert into temp table using IF

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following, I believe simple code, but I get this error:

> There is already an object named '#tableA' in the database

Is there a way to overcome this?

Thanks

```
DECLARE @dateA datetime2
SET @dateA = '2015-06-01'

IF @dateA <= '2019-01-01' 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tableA

    SELECT * 
    INTO #tableA 
    FROM view1 
    WHERE date = @dateA
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tableA

    SELECT * 
    INTO #tableA 
    FROM view2 
    WHERE date = @dateA
END
```

Comment: If `view1` and `view2` have the same schema, a safer approach is to unconditionally do a `SELECT TOP(0) * INTO #tableA FROM view1` to create the table (or, you know, just write out the `CREATE TABLE`), then do simple `INSERT`s. If they don't have the same schema, then using `#tableA` with essentially a dynamic schema is asking for trouble; such code may or may not end up working. If you do this often, consider creating a third view that just `UNION ALL`s `view1` and `view2` together with `WHERE` clauses to exclude the date cutoff, and select directly from that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert . . . Or explicitly use a `CREATE TABLE` statement to create `#tableA`. And instead of an additional view, two `INSERT ... SELECT` queries with a date cutoff in their WHERE clauses might do the job as well. :)

Comment: Thank you both. The create table statement would become laborious as I need to utilise this script in a lot of places, in any case I have found a solution by creating a function that returns view1 or view2 depending on a dateParam, and ineed that function essentials performs the create table as a function returning a table should. Thanks both.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql):

> `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur.

I assume that a `SELECT INTO` statement has the same issues since it also creates a new table.

How are you executing the SQL code?

- In a client app, I would try to first execute the `DROP TABLE` statement separately.
- In SSMS, putting the `DROP TABLE` statement in a separate batch will probably work:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tableA
GO

DECLARE @dateA datetime2
SET @dateA = '2015-06-01'

IF @dateA <= '2019-01-01' 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO #tableA
    FROM view1
    WHERE date = @dateA
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO #tableA
    FROM view2
    WHERE date = @dateA
END
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Bart however it unfortunately didn't work. I did however find a solution by creating a function that returns from either view depending on the date parameter. Cheers. Paul.

Comment: Ah yes. That's an alternative to Jeroen Mostert's third view approach. Glad it worked for you. :)

Comment: Yep. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a function that returns a table of the appropriate view given a date parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[return_view_depending_on_date](@dateChoice datetime2)

-- note: @returnTable, view1, view2, all must share identical schema/structure
RETURNS @returnTable TABLE (
    [col_one] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    ...etc
)

AS

BEGIN

    IF @dateChoice <= '2019-01-01'
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @returnTable SELECT * FROM view1 WHERE date_col= @dateChoice
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @returnTable SELECT * FROM view2 WHERE date_col= @dateChoice
        END

    RETURN

END
```